# Imagebutton doesnt work in slidinguppanel

Tags: java, android

I'm using the umano SlidingUpPanel library and I used an imagebutton in the panel but nothing happens when I click the imagebutton, I tried the imagebutton in another activity which worked perfectly. "next" is supposed to be printed to the logs when the button is pressed. I've searched all over but can't find any solution

Here's my code:

```
@SuppressLint("Registered")
public class NowPlaying extends Activity {

ImageButton play, pause, play_main, pause_main, next, imgbtn;

private MusicService musicSrv;


@SuppressLint("WrongViewCast")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.now_playing);

    play = findViewById(R.id.play_button);

    imgbtn = findViewById(R.id.imgbtn);
    imgbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @SuppressLint("ShowToast")
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.i("oladapos", "next");
        }
    });

    SlidingUpPanelLayout now_playing = 
findViewById(R.id.slideup_nowplaying);

    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            playNext();
        }
    });


}

//play next
private void playNext(){
    musicSrv.playNext();
}

//play previous
private void playPrev(){
    musicSrv.playPrev();
}

@Override
public void start() {

}

@Override
public void pause() {

}

@Override
public int getDuration() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public int getCurrentPosition() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void seekTo(int pos) {

}

@Override
public boolean isPlaying() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public int getBufferPercentage() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public boolean canPause() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean canSeekBackward() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean canSeekForward() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public int getAudioSessionId() {
    return 0;
}
}
```

xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/slideup_nowplaying"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
tools:context=".Fragments.songsFragment">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/songs_cover"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:focusable="true">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/songs_cover_one"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:src="@drawable/songs_cover"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_width="202dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/linearLayout3"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/songs_cover_one"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/songs_title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
                android:lines="1"
                android:text="@string/havana_camila_cabello_song"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="22sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/songs_artist_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:lines="1"
                android:text="@string/camila_cabello" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.974"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/play_button"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:src="@drawable/round_play_arrow_black_48dp" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/forword_button"
        android:id="@+id/imgbtn"/>

</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: set height to wrap_content of relative layout in which your image button is.

Comment: It's not that, the button is clickable but it does nothing when clicked.

Comment: use Log.d("oladapos","next") and remove extra semicolumn. And in your log serach "oladapos" keyword.

Comment: Its neither the extra semicolon nor using "Log.d"..just doesn't work